# Where can I ask about analog security camera wiring?

Tags: support, site-recommendation, asking-questions

I have a question about using different types of cables (e.g. CAT6 [SU]TP) for signal and power runs to analog video cameras (that normally run with co-ax) as part of a security system (residential). The reason I'd like to use different types of cables is to make installation easier, and the reason I want to ask about it is because I'm not sure what types of cables can carry the signals effectively while preserving quality.

Three sites immediately come to mind:

- [Video Production](https://video.stackexchange.com) - I imagine the people here will know about video signals over different types of cables and, as a bonus, perhaps know about other A/V-centric solutions. My system can run in any of CVBS / AHD / TVI / CVI modes and this is the only site where I feel like people would know what those stand for.
- [Electrical Engineering](https://electronics.stackexchange.com) - I imagine the people here will have a good understanding of things like signal loss and EM noise, which is a major part of my question.
- [Home Improvement](https://diy.stackexchange.com) - Since it's a security system in the residential building that I live in. Also, since the reason behind my question is to make installation simpler, they may know some good installation strategies.

Which ones *can* I ask on, and, of those, which one is my best bet?

Comment: After some thought; I think I'm going to do a little more product hunting first (my situation does not appear to be uncommon). Then, if I still have questions, I suspect they'll be reduced to much more specific topics and an easier choice of site.

Comment: Hi Jason - it would be off topic on Video Production.

Comment: Here is a partial duplicate: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/173164/142621 at EE, and some advice to help you compose your question:   https://ipvm.com/forums/video-surveillance/topics/cat6-vs-coaxial-cable-for-analog-camera

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've seen this being done - and its kinda 'bodgy' - the installers are not EEs (basically slightly trained electricians of the blue collar sort) , and there's quite a lot of specific weirdness to this, like baluns and and such, and specific setups that involve wiring up your UTP cables for power directly into a box. No one working on it got 'how' it worked, only that it did.

I'd say [Home Improvement](https://diy.stackexchange.com/), though I personally don't know enough to *answer*.

Comment: Thanks. Yeah I'm cognizant of the weirdness; that's why I'm leaning more towards the video.se side of the fence honestly -- those "other A/V-centric solutions" I vaguely mentioned are things like baluns, or multiplexers with co-ax runs, or other devices I'd like to have but I'm not sure if they actually exist. I just didn't want to include all the details of the full question here.

Comment: Many of them are security camera centric 

Comment: Heh, good point. Well, you know; I might end up not having to post this question after all: [signal + power -> rj45 baluns](https://www.cctvcamerapros.com/RJ45-Balun-p/vb-2vpa.htm), with the bonus of not having to hack BNC and barrel connectors to the ends of CAT5. Now to hunt for a version that can pack 2 or 3 cameras into a single cable (plus some math to check if I can power 2 or 3 off a single power supply line).

Comment: I think I'm going to do a little more product hunting first. Then, if I still have questions, I suspect they'll be reduced to much more specific topics and an easier choice of site.

Comment: Yeah, customer service on a security camera site helped me figure it all out. Got it all sorted out now.